# Is my Finnish Schengen residence permit (issued for work) still valid if I'm no longer employed?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, residency, finland

I have a residence permit (Finland), the valid days as per permit card is until June 30, 2016. I de-registered my SSN and moved out of Finland on October, 2015. Now I would like to travel to Germany, Italy and Switzerland for a week (June 3rd - June 11) for leisure.

Can I go ahead with this travel with the same residence permit? Or will this be a problem?

Comment: What does "de-registered SSN" mean here? The question title seems to imply it is something you did in your home country, but what _is_ your home country?

Comment: It appears that Finland calls their social security numbers SSNs (like the US), so I presume the OP previously took steps to end their Finnish residency, but still holds a residency permit valid until the end of June.

Comment: This question is about traveling, not the work part, and does not belong to Expats but here on Travel SE. Voted to leave open.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for Finnish Schengen visa but I did the same when I was working in Germany. I was granted a working visa which was Type 'D' where I was allowed to travel within Schengen countries. I finished my employment earlier than I thought so I went back to the UK. I decided to go back to Berlin again for leisure with the same visa. I was allowed in without any problem. The immigration officer didn't ask me a question. I did that twice and I didn't have any problems.

My friend was in the same situation and the immigration officer asked her what she was doing there and she just simply answered that she's there for business and she didn't have any problem.

This doesn't mean that it would be the same for everyone. The best thing would be to check with the embassy of your point of entry.